# Multiply and sum items of 2 lists using stream in Java

Tags: java, java-stream

I have 2 lists. One that I get the values of my database and others that I get as input.
I have to multiply the value of `productQuantity` (HerdList) by `proporcionValue` (HerdCompositionList) that matches the primary key (productCode, ageRangeCode) and sum the values.

Below is the code with the `for` loop. How do I do it with streams?

```
Herd (Input)
    int productCode;
    int ageRangeCode;
    int productQuantity;

HerdComposition (DB)
    Integer productCode;
    Integer ageRangeCode;
    BigDecimal proporcionValue;

for (Herd informedItem : prodution.getHerdList()) {
    for (HerdComposition herdItem : HerdCompositionList) {
        if (herdItem.getProductCode() == informedItem.getProductCode() 
            && herdItem.getAgeRangeCode() == informedItem.getAgeRangeCode()) {
            totalHerd = totalHerd
                .add(herdItem.getProporcionValue()
                    .multiply(new BigDecimal(informedItem.getProductQuantity())));
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Have you already tried something? And what is the type of `totalHerd`?

Comment: Provide Java code please.

Comment: Is it possible that the combination of `productCode` and `ageRangeCode` is same for multiple elements in your lists?

Comment: If it works as written why rewrite it just to use streams?

Answer (score 2):

Since you've mentioned the primary key as `(productCode, ageRangeCode)`, you can create a quantity lookup map from the input list:

```
Map<List<?>, Integer> productQuantityLookUp = herdList.stream()
        .collect(Collectors.toMap(
                h -> Arrays.asList(h.getProductCode(), h.getAgeRangeCode()),
                Herd::getProductQuantity));
```

further, iterate over the database list and reduce it to get the total

```
BigDecimal totalHerd = herdCompositionList.stream()
        .map(hc -> new BigDecimal(productQuantityLookUp
                .getOrDefault(Arrays.asList(hc.getProductCode(), hc.getAgeRangeCode()), 0))
                .multiply(hc.getProporcionValue()))
        .reduce(BigDecimal.ZERO, BigDecimal::add);
```

One of the benefits of using this approach (not specifically stream), would be that your complexity would reduce from `O(N*M)` to `O(N+M)` for `M` times `O(1)` lookup of the intermediate map.